# Aplicar bordes a las celdas en Excel usando Apache POI en JAVA

Tags: java, apache-poi

Estoy usando **XSSFWorkbook** para generar un documento de Excel (.xlsx), pero, no he logrado aplicar bordes a las celdas usando:

```
XSSFCellStyle style3 = workbook.createCellStyle();
style3.setBorderBottom(XSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
style3.setBorderTop(XSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
style3.setBorderRight(XSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
style3.setBorderLeft(XSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
```

Error que recibo:

> BORDER_MEDIUM cannot be resolved or is not a field

Librerías que tengo importadas:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.HorizontalAlignment;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFont;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
```

.jar's de mi proyecto:

1. commons-collections4-4.1
2. poi-3.17
3. poi-ooxml-3.17
4. poi-ooxml-schemas-3.17
5. xmlbeans-2.6.0

Me falta algún `.jar`, cuál?. He investigado y no he encontrado una solución.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me parece que estas usando codigo antiguo con una version mas nueva de poi.

El api en la url: https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFCellStyle.html#setBorderBottom-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.BorderStyle-
Específica que el metodo recibe el enum `BorderStyle`

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.BorderStyle;

style.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.MEDIUM);
```